# SharePoint Server 2010 July 2015 CU install status shows superseded

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration

I just installed the SharePoint Server 2010 July 2015 CU (uber update) and now in central admin, under 'Manage Patch Status', a lot of updates now say 'Superseded'.  I can't find much info as to what it means.  Do I need to reinstall those patches?

Comment: Did you run the psconfig wizards after installing the package?

Comment: Yup, I ran the wizard and then the psconfig in powershell.  The update says successful, but I'm just wondering why a lot of my other patches now say 'superseded'.

Comment: Could u please share the patch numbers? July cu patch says superseded or not?

Comment: These are the ones listed as superseded (I only put some of them, as it is a rather larger list). Per the anser the HPD, it seems that they are no longer required because a newer patch supersedes it.. but strange they are still listed:Security Update for 2010 Microsoft Business Productivity Servers (KB2553298) 64-Bit Edition, Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2825786) 64-Bit Edition, Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3054975) 64-Bit Edition, Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3054975) 64-Bit Edition

Answer (score 2):

The updates listed as "Superseded" have been replaced by the newer patch. I don't why the older patches are still listed - maybe to provide some sort of patch install history?

There's a TechNet article that explains these, I'll quote the relevant text below in case the link or article text changes.

"Software updates overview for SharePoint 2013" at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806329(v=office.15).aspx

- **Installed** - Indicates that no action is required.
- **Missing/Required** - Displayed if a product is required on each server or if a patch for a specific .msi file is located on one server but not on the server for which this status is shown
- **Missing/Optional** - Displayed if a product is not required on each server
- **Superseded** - Displayed if an update is no longer required on a server because a newer patch supersedes it